# Training and test diverge while running catboost

Tags: catboost, catboostregressor

When I run the catboost regressor my training and test plots diverge with weird kinks at ~1000 iterations. The plot is appended below and my regressor setup is as follows:

```
cat_model=CatBoostRegressor(iterations=2500, depth=4, learning_rate=0.01, loss_function='RMSE', thread_count=-1, use_best_model = True, random_seed=12, random_strength=10, rsm=0.5)
```

I tried different values of leaf_estimation_iterations & bagging_temperature but did not get any success. Any suggestions on what i should try to get better results.

[Model Fit Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbLJN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The diverge is normal. you will always perform better on the train set, as the model overfits the training set, and your objective is to regulate it with the validation set.

First I would recommend to read on bias vs variance tradeoff for a general intuition on how to tackle this issue.

specifically for catboost, you would like to regularize the training procedure so it would generalize better. 
you can start with adding more data, and set higher `l2_leaf_reg` parameter.

The official documentation have much more good suggestions on model tuning:
https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/parameter-tuning.html